# Como dar reload em uma WebViewer por intervalo de tempo no Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, mobile, xamarin, webview

Estou criando um aplicativo, onde possui um [WebView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/) que precisa ser atualizado de 5 em 5 segundos enquanto o [Switch](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Switch/) estiver marcado, e quando desmarca-lo, ele deverá fazer a página parar de carregar.

Tentei utilizar um while, mas o aplicativo fica esperando o while e durante isso ele congela, se poderem me ajudar com este problema ficarei muito grato!

Meu código atual:

```
nswtURL.Click += delegate
                {
                    if (nswtURL.Checked)
                    {
                        //true
                        nWebView.LoadUrl(URL);
                        while(nswtCamera.Checked)
                        {
                            nWebView.Reload();
                            Thread.Sleep(5);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //false
                        nWebView.StopLoading();
                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 1):

Essa estratégia não é tão performática, pois isso vai, de fato travar o App, afinal a main thread estará travada nesse `while (Thread.Sleep(5);)`.

Recomendo assinar o evento `CheckedChange` do switcher, toda vez que ele sofrer alteração, vai invocar esse evento. Algo como

```
nswtURL.CheckedChange += CheckedChangeEvent;
void CheckedChangeEvent(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
{
    //Verificar o e.IsChecked
}
```

Para atualizar de 5 em 5 segundos, dentro desse evento, você pode usar um `System.Threading.Timer`. Algo como:

```
timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback((o) => {
    nWebView.Reload();
    RunOnUiThread(() => {
        //aqui você pode atualizar sua tela
        nWebView.Reload();
    });
}), null, 5000, 5000);
```

Para parar o `Timer`, dê um dispose: `timer.Dispose()`. Esse controle de iniciar e parar fica a cargo da mudança do `e.IsChecked`.

Só tome cuidado pq certamente esses métodos vão consumir muita bateria. Você pode adicionar uma estratégia de deixar o usuário atualizar a tela. Claro que cada caso é um caso, mas com certeza a bateria vai ser drenada aqui :/